# Load facebook social plugin in side chrome extension("manifest_version": 2)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, facebook-social-plugins

Previously I have loaded facebook comment plugin in side my chrmoe extension with manifest version 01. Now I updated version to manifest version 02 and then I have to do couple of changers in my extension code base.

According to the new version we can not load the external js file without specifying external resources associate with "content_security_policy". Anyway this is my new manifest.json file,

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.13",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "",
  "background": "background.html",
  "icons": { "128": "fb_bug.gif" },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://connect.facebook.net/; object-src 'self'",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "plugin_content.html"
  },
   "permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "background",
    "cookies"
  ],"web_accessible_resources": [
    "css/extension.css",
    "js/config.js",
    "js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"
    "js/extension.js",
    "images/loaderImg.gif",
    "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
  ]
}
```

Now when I load the extension it raises a following error and facebook social plugin is not working.

"error: Code generation from strings disallowed for this context  all.js:41"

Is there anyone who know solution for this matter.

Comment: Is Anyone having any idea about this. I am still finding a way to do this stuff.

Comment: There is no work around - other than to keep using manifest version 1 for now. To work with manifest version 2, they will need to provide a new version of all.js that does not use eval or Function(). Extensions that use manifest version 1 will continue to work for quite some time. See chrome://chrome/extensions/ for the full timeline.

Comment: But we can not use version 1 and upload extension to google chrome extension directory. It keep asking to update version 2. Therefor eather party should give a solution for this matter. Is there anyone having with quick fix for this matter

Answer (score 0):

sorry it took so long to reply to this.

I'm an Engineer at Facebook and tried looking at alternatives to remove the one Function() we use in the SDK, but unfortunately there is no way to reliably remove it without breaking functionality. Other seem to have the same problem and I didn't find anyone that was able to solve this issue in an efficient way.

However, according to this comment on the Chromium issue tracker (http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107538#c69), you should be able to solve this by adding a `content_security_policy` attribute to your manifest that whitelists `'unsafe-eval'` for `script-src`:

```
    {
        ...
        "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
        ...
    }
```

Comment: This is giving the following error,  "chrome'. Invalid value for 'content_security_policy'."

Comment: Hey @Ananda, looking into it.